# How do I change the (fill/stroke) color of multiple (Illustrator) files in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, workflow, import

Is there a way that I can change the fill color of multiple linked .ai files all at once in InDesign? My process is as follows:

I'm working on a photobook in InDesign. I've a master page with various linked icon images that are one color (currently .psd format) and a frame that will contain a different vector filled Illustrator file on each page (see screenshot). They have the same fill color as the icon images.

The layout of the master page is finished but I'm not yet satisfied with the color scheme. I want to be able to see the effects when I change the color in my InDesign layout (the icons and the different illustrator files). The proces of opening up every individual file in Illustrator and Photoshop to change its fill color is a time consuming time. So that's why I wonder if there is a smarter solution to change the fill color of my linked .ai (and .psd files).

[image: Explanation]

Comment: No But one could be made. In this case though would be easier to bring teh shape into indesign as a path

Comment: This question is really similar to this one: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/94279/is-there-a-way-to-test-a-color-series-of-ai-graphics-placed-in-indesign Have a look at my answer there, it may be acceptable for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the object. So instead of object colored in gray have it transparent while everything else is white.
Then, in indesing, just change the object color to chosen one.

OR

Copy & Paste the object to the Indesing so it will behave as regular object and not placed file.

Comment: The reverse object is a smart idea although I might have a slightly gradient background. Haven't thought about the copy/paste action but that works perfect. Is there any downside in using it that way?

Comment: The main downside is that it won't be linked to file. So any change made to one instance would show only in that instance.